# jquery not updating iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here's what I have at http://127.0.0.1/test.html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%" src="blank.html"></iframe>
<script>
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').html('aaa');
</script>
```

Here's what I have at http://127.0.0.1/blank.html:

```
<body>zzz</body>
```

I'd expect the iframe'd contents to be "aaa" but they're not - they're "zzz". It's as though the `$('iframe').contents().find('body').html('aaa');` except that I'm not getting an error in the console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in a load event handler

```
$('iframe').on('load', function(){
   $(this).contents().find('body').html('aaa');
})
```